# Can I run Python based ML model with external libraries dependencies in Cloudera Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, cloudera

A bit new to to **Python and ML models**. We have a **Cloudera data platform** in place and want to harness the power of Spark to run **Reinforcement Learning Model**. This model has **dependency on a external Python libraries** which are **not available in the PySpark** shipped with Cloudera platform.

Is there a possibility to execute the model as a **Spark** job and let **YARN** handle it by adding those external libraries somehow? Tried to execute the Python code without Spark and it choked the edge node since the job was running only on the edge node and not the cluster itself?

Any leads?

regards,